# How do I remove a repository from SmartGit?

Tags: git, smartgit

How do I remove a local repository from SmartGit v7?

If I delete the repository from disk it still appears in my list of repositories but with `<missing>` after it.

I cannot see any way of removing it from the UI.

Comment: I don't use SmartGit, but is there no right-click menu to untrack the folder from the UI?

Comment: Nope, I've checked all the menus, context and main, and there doesn't appear to be any remove or untrack option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the repo and choose "Remove" item. Note that you have to *close* the repo to be able to do this. One way to close the repo is to right click on it and choose "Close" item. Another way is to *open* a different repo.

Answer (score 2):

delete the .git folder and it will remove it

Comment: Done that and it gives me the <missing> tag after the repository name but it is still present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just figured it out. [codeWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598/codewizard) was almost there, deleting it from disk was the correct solution, but I needed to restart smartgit.

On restart smartGit asks if I want to remove any missing repositories. There doesn't appear to be a way of doing this without restarting the program.

Comment: Although this answer does work, Mikhails answer is better.